# Using glDrawElements with multiple meshes

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, rendering

I can succesfully draw a scene with glDrawArrays which looks like this:
[image]

This technique is a bit slow so i decided to make a indexbuffer and tried to use glDrawElements. The result of that looks like this:

[image]

As you probably can see, the squares top right are rendered incorrectly and square below the airplane dissappeared.

The code for generating the buffers

```
//create vertex and index buffer 
glGenBuffers(1, &gVertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gVertexBuffer);   
glGenBuffers(1, &gIndexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, gIndexBuffer);

// Define the size of the buffers   
GLuint floatAmount = 0;
GLuint GLuintAmount = 0;
for each (MeshObject* mesh in meshes)
{
    floatAmount += mesh->GetFloatAmount();
    GLuintAmount += mesh->GetGLuintAmount();
}
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, floatAmount, 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, GLuintAmount, 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


// Define size and offset of the different subdata in the buffers
GLuint offsetVer = 0;
GLuint offsetInd = 0;
for each (MeshObject* mesh in meshes)
{
    // Set offset for mesh
    mesh->SetOffset(offsetVer / sizeof(Point));
    mesh->SetOffsetInd(offsetInd);

    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
        offsetVer,
        mesh->GetFloatAmount(),
        mesh->GetPoints().data());

    glBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
        offsetInd,
        mesh->GetGLuintAmount(),
        mesh->GetIndicies().data());

    offsetVer += mesh->GetFloatAmount();
    offsetInd += mesh->GetGLuintAmount();
}
```

... and the code for the rendering

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gVertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, gIndexBuffer);

mat4 vwMatrix = localCamera->GetPVMatrix() * mh->GetWorld();

glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionviewworldMatrixUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &(GLfloat)vwMatrix[0][0]);

//glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, mh->mesh->GetOffset(), mh->mesh->GetPoints().size());
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mh->mesh->GetIndicies().size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)mh->mesh->GetOffsetInd());

//GLuint size = mh->mesh->GetIndicies().size();
//GLuint IndSize = mh->mesh->GetOffsetInd();
//glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, size, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)IndSize);
```

Comment: What does `mesh->SetOffset(offsetVer / sizeof(Point)); mesh->SetOffsetInd(offsetInd);` do?

Comment: The first one, offsetVer, is not used for glDrawElements But for glDrawArrays. It is an offset and works as intended but probably useless in this case. The second one, offsetInd, is the offset I want to have for the last Parameter in glDrawElements but I don´t know if it´s the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `offsetVer` on each element of the index buffer. Here is an example:

Mesh A ( 1 triangle)

```
Vertices: v0 v1 v2
Indices: 0 1 2
```

Mesh B ( 1 triangle)

```
Vertices: v3 v4 v5
Indices: 0 1 2
```

That is how your combined buffer looks like:

```
Vertices: v0 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
Indices: 0 1 2 0 1 2
```

That is how it should be:

```
Vertices: v0 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
Indices: 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: It solved my problem but additions made creating of the buffers slower. ( for (GLuint i = 0; i < mesh->GetIndicies().size(); i++) { mesh->indicies[i] += offsetVer / sizeof(Point); } ). Do you know a quicker way to do this or is it impossible to optimize?

Comment: If you move the division out of the loop this method will only add 1 additional fixed point addition per index. This should be hardly noticeable on modern CPUs since such a loop can be optimized pretty well and can be neglected considering the fact you have to load the mesh from hard drive which should have a much bigger impact on the performance.

Comment: I moved the divisions and noticed no real difference. What made the difference (and it should be a warning for everyone that uses the std::vector) is the call to the function size(). If I saved the variable and avoided making the call 68500 times (Index cound of the airplane mesh) the startup was more or less instant. I find this a bit ridiculous actually :-)